# Suppose $ a, b, c, d $ are nonzero elements in UFD and we can deduce $ a|c $ from $ ab|cd $, then $ d|b $

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I came up with this question when I was trying to solve another problem about modules.

> Suppose $ a, b, c, d $ are nonzero elements in UFD and we can deduce $ a|c $ from $ ab|cd $, then $ d|b $.

I have posted my solution below.

Comment: @darijgrinberg $ ((\forall a, b, c, d\neq 0, a, b, c, d\in UFD)\wedge(ab|cd)\rightarrow a|c)\rightarrow (d|b) $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $ a=\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i^{a_i}, b=\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i^{b_i}, c=\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i^{c_i}, d=\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i^{d_i} $(omit the units), where $ 
p_i $ are distinct primes. Then $ ab=\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i^{a_i+b_i} $ and $ cd=\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{c_i+d_i} $ with $ a_i+b_i\leq c_i+d_i $. Since we can always deduce $ a_i\leq c_i $ from above, then $ b_i \geq d_i $, i.e. $ d|b $.